# Need help optimizing 4 heavy queries on one webpage

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have [four](http://pastebin.com/CjWybku0) queries that run on one web page. I use them for statistics and they are taking too long to load.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/qxqPkjcT) are my current configurations

use the text wrapping button on pastebin to make it easier to read.

I have a lot of RAM dedicated to mysql but it still takes a long time. I have also index most of the columns.

I'm just trying to see what other options I have.

I put "show create table" and total count(*) in [here](http://pastebin.com/zHDYyEpM). I'm going to rename everything and paste in SO. I agree that someone in the future may use it.

Comment: Please put all necessary info directly into your question. Links break and we want to preserve posts for future visitors

Comment: i have sensitive data that I do not want on the net.

Comment: @Dev-Ria You just posted it to the net...

Comment: Correct. pastebin expires.

Comment: Then anonymize your data and post it into your question.

Comment: Reduce your code to the general core problem.

Comment: I have. the core problem are my four queries. I provided "Explain" and my config to show how my system is running. I could have just pasted queries with nothing else but that's useless.

Comment: Typically, we also need the schema to answer performance questions.

Comment: If you want us to help optimize a query, **you need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  We also need row counts because that can affect query optimization greatly.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: I'll have that up as well in a sec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### QUERY ONE

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 
      DATE_FORMAT(DateActioned,'%M-%Y') as val1, 
      COUNT(*) AS total_count
   FROM 
      db.statisticsresults
   WHERE 
          DID = 28
      AND ActionTypeID = 1 
      AND DateActioned IS NOT NULL 
   GROUP BY 
      DATE_FORMAT(DateActioned, '%m-%y')
   ORDER BY
      YEAR( DateActioned ) DESC,
      MONTH( DateActioned ) DESC
```

This, I would have a covering index based on your key elements so the engine does not have to go back to the raw data... Based on this and your following queries, I would have THAT column in the primary index position such as

```
StatisticsResults -- index ( DID, ActionTypeID, DateActioned )
```

The order by by respective year() descending and month() descending will do the same thing as your hard-coded references to FIND the field in the list.

### QUERY TWO

-- 381.812

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE 
      DATE_FORMAT(DateActioned,'%M-%Y') as val1, 
      COUNT(*) AS total_count
   FROM 
      db.statisticsdivision
   WHERE 
          DID = 28
      AND ActionTypeID = 9 
      AND DateActioned IS NOT NULL 
   GROUP BY 
      DATE_FORMAT(DateActioned, '%m-%y')
   ORDER BY 
      YEAR( DateActioned ) DESC,
      MONTH( DateActioned ) DESC
```

ON this one, the DID = '28', I changed to DID = 28.  If the column is numeric, don't offer confusion to the engine to try and convert one to the other.  The same indexes from option 1 would apply here too.

### QUERY THREE

-- 33.899

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT 
      AID, 
      COUNT(*) AS acount 
   FROM 
      db.statisticsresults
         JOIN db.division_id USING(AID)
   WHERE 
      DID = 28
   GROUP BY 
      AID
   ORDER BY 
      count(*) DESC 
   LIMIT 
      19
```

This one looks like a bit of a waste... you are joining to the division table based on an "AID" column in the stats table.  Why are you doing the join unless you actually are expecting some invalid "AID" values not in the division table?  Again, change your  "DID" column to 28 instead of '28'.  Ensure your division table has its index on "AID" for the join.  The SECOND index from query 1 appears to be your better option

### QUERY FOUR

-- 21.403

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE DISTINCT 
      TID, 
      tax, 
      agent, 
      COUNT(*) AS t_count 
   FROM 
      db.statisticsresults sr
         JOIN db.tax_id USING(TID)
            JOIN db.agent_id ai ON(ai.AID = sr.AID)
   WHERE 
      DID = 28 
   GROUP BY 
      TID, 
      sr.AID 
   ORDER BY 
      COUNT(*) DESC 
   LIMIT 19
```

Again, "DID" column from '28' to 28

FOR your TAX_ID table, have a covering index on that too so it can handle the join 
TO the agent table without going TO the raw page data

```
Tax_ID -- index ( tid, aid )
```

Finally, if you are dealing with your original list finding things only from Jan 2012 to Dec 2013, you can simplify querying the ENTIRE table of stats by adding to your WHERE clause...

```
   AND DateActioned >= '2012-01-01'
```

So you completely skip over anything prior to 2012 (old data I presume?)

Comment: @DevRia, just for grins, how are the final query performances with the index and adjustments.

Comment: they went from 380+ seconds to 3.167 seconds! Thank you for the great advice!!